# already up to date

Tags: git, github

Quiero que kotlin se sincronize con origin/programacionandroid pero cada vez que hago pull me indica already up to date
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Subir código y mensajes en consola como imagen [es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Esta es la [traducción de _already up to date_](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/es/already%20up%20to%20date). ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: podrias indicar cual es tu rama actual (parece que es `jadsksj`) y qué comando ejecutas? para indicar que trata de mezclar `origin/programacionandroid`?